# setLayoutParams resets ImageView position

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that can be moved across the screen. The problem is that when I want to change width and height of the ImageView, ImageView resets to its start position and then resizes.

I would like that the ImageView stay in the same position it was.
Is there a way to do that?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (200 * scale + 0.5f), (int) (250 * scale + 0.5f));
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should use it this way:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = (int) (200 * scale + 0.5f);
layoutParams.height = (int) (250 * scale + 0.5f);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); //I think this part might not be needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the property animator to achieve this. On your view you should implement something like this:

```
yourView.animate().scaleX(xValue).scaleY(yValue).setDuration(durationMillis);
```

I hope this helps.